# retrieve data from a collection in meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am trying to display a summation of all of the information that was submitted in a form.

```js
Template.SingleDailylog.helpers({
  personInCharge: ()=>{
    const id = FlowRouter.getParam('id');
    const profile = Dailylog.findOne({_id:id});
    const name = profile.personInCharge;
    return name;
    }
});
```

```html
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <input value="{{personInCharge}}" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name">
    <label for="first">Person In Charge</label>
</div>
```

This does insert the information, but I am still getting an error:

> meteor.js?hash=0504f43f667698535416b00eb44eb6f53161cb63:1048 Exception in template helper: TypeError: Cannot read property 'personInCharge' of undefined
>       at Object.personInCharge (http://localhost:3000/app/app.js?hash=e537a3bd311bc41765fe473a7cd9cf9609139dc9:8544:26)
>       at http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?hash=adc5286b78e5c0f8e7f56a602f77eefb5def6bf1:3051:16
>       at http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?hash=adc5286b78e5c0f8e7f56a602f77eefb5def6bf1:1715:16
>       at http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?hash=adc5286b78e5c0f8e7f56a602f77eefb5def6bf1:3103:66
>       at Function.Template._withTemplateInstanceFunc

How am I getting an error, but the data that is displayed is correct? This is preventing me from saving edits to the data.

Comment: It is very likely because in the first render the subscription has not been ready and thus the helper throws an error. Then once the sub is ready the data is available, no error and your input value is set to whatever the name is.

Answer (score 1):

The helper is trying to access a nested value (`personInCharge`) from an object that does not exist yet (`profile`)

If you want to prevent this exception from occurring, you have two options here:

### Option 1 - Prevent access to undefined Objects inside the helper

You could for example maybe wrap each of your variables in an if statement like so:

```
Template.SingleDailylog.helpers({
  personInCharge: ()=>{
    const id, profile, name;

    id = FlowRouter.getParam('id');

    if (id) {
        profile = Dailylog.findOne({_id:id});
    }
    if (profile && profile.personInCharge) { // I always check nested things this way
        name = profile.personInCharge;
    }
    if (name) {
        return name;
    }

});
```

In this case, if `id` and `profile` and `profile.personInCharge` are undefined, the code in the if blocks won't execute, and therefore it won't be trying to access nested variables that don't exist yet when the template is created, which will keep the helper from throwing exceptions.

### Option 2 - Prevent the helper from being called

You could also use a reactive variable to indicate, whether the subscription is ready and prevent the template from calling the helper, if not.

// const subscription = //... use this if you use a global suscription

```
Template.SingleDailylog.onCreated (function () {
  const instance = this;
  instance.state = new ReactiveDict();
  instance.autorun(() => {
    const subscription = //... use this for Template level subscription
    if (subscription.ready()) {
      instance.state.set('loadComplete', true);
    }
  });
})
```

Then add a helper for `loadComplete`:

```
Template.SingleDailylog.helpers({
  personInCharge() {
    const id = FlowRouter.getParam('id');
    const profile = Dailylog.findOne({_id:id});
    const name = profile.personInCharge;
    return name;
  },
  loadComplete () {
    return Template.instance().state.get('loadComplete');
  }
});
```

and use it to call the `personInCharge` helper only if `loadComplete` is true:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
    {{#if loadComplete}}
    <input value="{{personInCharge}}" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name">
    <label for="first">Person In Charge</label>
    {{else}}
    <div>Loading....</div>
    {{/if}}
</div>
```

Comment: I added another option, so you can choose which fits better to your current code.

Comment: @Jankapunkt thank you so much for your response. I tried option 1 and the errors disappeared!! But I'm not sure how to manipulate it to get a date. With the code:

Comment: Template.SingleDailylog.helpers({
  date: function(){
  const id = FlowRouter.getParam('id');
  if (id){
  profile = Dailylog.findOne({_id:id}); }
  if (profile && profile.date){
  name = profile.date;}
  if (name){
  return moment(name).format('MM/DD/YYYY');} },
I get the error: Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized ISO format. moment construction falls back to js Date(), which is not reliable across all browsers and versions

Comment: @Kassie if the solution helped you, please upvote and accept (note, that option 1 is provided by @Ticdoc). Regarding your other issue I suggest you to open a new question, specific to the date error (because the error has nothing to do with Meteor or Template helpers).